# How to switch what I see in Blend?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

Very simple question.. I'm into learning Blend (way hard for developer..)

So. I'm editing `TabControl`s template. Tabs have different templates. `TopSelected`, `TopUnselected` and so on.

[image]

I want to edit `OverlappingTabUnSelected` path but no matter what I click - I still see `OverlappingTab` in designer view. How do I switch from template to template? Even though I see proper item selected - actual design shows is from different templat. What am I doing wrong? I feel really stupid..

[image]

One more image showing that I'm selecting state:
[image]

Comment: It does not seem to be a default template of a TabControl or am I wrong? Perhaps for some reason the visual state is not switching correctly due to an issue in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a template has Visual States, you need to select the correct Visual State (Focused, Unfocused, Selected UnSelected) in order to edit the template.

Are you choosing the SelectionStates.Unselected State in the Visual State Manager (States) pane?

Comment: Walt, see my edit. I tried different things - no change. Maybe I'm not selecting properly? I bet it's something very obvious but it just doesn't work for me..

Comment: I found issue. I had grid's set to "collapsed" and only active one was set from code so switching templates didn't work. Changed visibility and now when choosing Visual Styles work

Comment: OK. So now you the grid is set to Visibililty=Visible.

Comment: It works, kind of. But I need to switch it to collapsed before running otherwise it does it at run time :)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe that the order that the items occur in the list (from top to bottom) determines the order that they appear on the screen.

Have you tried selecting one of the items that you wish to change the visibility of and dragging it above (or below) another item?

Comment: Hmm Sorry - I thought it was worth a try. It has been a while since I have used Blend.

Comment: You can use the Show/Hide Icon in the  Object and Timeline view to view obscured items (click on the 'Eye' button on the right side). Changing the visibility of an item by dragging it up/down the list changes the ZIndex property which can have significant impact on the element layout.  Doing this is a complex layout is asking for trouble.